# Using a stored procedure in entity framework, how do I get the entity to have its navigation properties populated?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

Entity framework is cripplingly slow so I tried using a stored procedure but I ran into this problem.

Entity Framework allows you to define a stored procedure that produces an entity. However my entity has 'navigation properties' which are not being populated when using this method.

Is there a work around?

Comment: Maybe you could give us some examples of what you are doing with EF that is 'cripplingly slow'? I have not found EF to be noticeably slower in most cases unless I'm doing something that causes it to be inefficient.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well stored procedures are not composable. So there is no way to call your SPROC and have the EF automatically populate relationships in the same query, using Include() or something.

So say you have products and categories

and you have a sproc to get Products:

i.e.

```
var products = context.GetProducts(someproductfilter);
```

the resulting products won't have their categories loaded.

However if you have a second stored procedure that gets the Categories for said products:

i.e.

```
var categories = context.GetCategoriesForProducts(someproductfilter);
```

a feature in EF called relationship fixup, which links related entities once the second entity enters the context, will insure that after both calls are made, each product in products will have a non-null Category.

This is not ideal, because you are doing more than one query, but it will work.

An alternative is to use [EFExtensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/meek/archive/2008/03/26/ado-entity-framework-stored-procedure-customization.aspx). The guy who wrote that created the ability to write sprocs that load more data in one go.

Hope this helps

Cheers
Alex

Comment: Is this answer up to date? - I'm looking for exactly the same as OP.

Comment: @KristianNissen did you ever find out if there is a better way? Has been 5 years so hopefully EF6 has a solution.

Answer (score 5):

I found this SO question when researching Stored Procedures (SPs) with EF. I also see people like @KristianNissen and @Todilo have asked if there is an update with EF6.

The answer is yes, EF 6 has changed things, but it did not add anything to help load navigational properties when using SPs. Nor can you use the .Include() method with SPs as was asked in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335511/using-include-on-a-storeprocedure-with-ef?lq=1).

The only way is to write your SP to specifically load the navigational properties. However there is now some good Microsoft documentation on using SPs - see [Query SP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj557860) and [SP returning multiple result sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

For completeness the change that EF version 6 brought in was to allow Stored Procedures (SPs) to handle insert, update and delete - see [Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx) and [Entity Framework Tutotial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/CRUD-using-stored-procedures.aspx).