# How to get values returned by stored precedure in MySql + EntityFramewrok

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

We are using EntityFramework and CodeFirst with MySql Database. In DB I created a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetDepartmentPath`(leftKey INT, rightKey INT)
BEGIN
.....
END
```

I tried executing code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845246/does-entity-framework-code-first-support-stored-procedures) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544061/stored-procedures-and-ef-code-first)(what is very similar to first link), but I always get a NotSupportedExeption. Is there a simple way to execute stored procedures using codefirst and get just a collection of entities?

Comment: have you had any luck with the above problem. I have encountered a similar problem and was wondering what your solution was. thanks