# Repopulate Entity Framework Navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Hi I have an MVC app I'm calling a stored procedure from. The reason I'm using a stored procedure is because the query is quite complex and it already exists so I may as well use it.

It basically returns to me a :

```
IEnumerable<Activity>
```

which is good.

There is a one of many foreign key properties like:

```
AreaId
```

on this which gets populated.

However in my model I have the navigation property:

```
// Navigation properties
        public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
```

which of course isn't populated getting it via the stored procedure.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to get these navigation properties populated.

I believe I have heard of some command you can call on you entity to refresh navigation properties.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035677/using-a-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-how-do-i-get-the-the-entity-to-have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
context.Entry(loadedEntity).Reference(l => l.Area).Load();
```

but it will not have nice performance if you call it for every entity in your enumeration because it will do separate query and database roundtrip for every `Area` you want to load. That is disadvantage of using stored procedures - once you go this way you should have another stored procedure to load all needed areas.